# Permutations II, remove duplicates in recursion

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of numbers with duplicate number in it. Find all unique permutations.

```
For numbers [1,2,2] the unique permutations are:
[
  [1,2,2],
  [2,1,2],
  [2,2,1]
]
```

In the method which is called hepler, in order to remove the duplicates, I have an if statement:

```
if (i != 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1] && !set.contains(i-1) ) {
    continue;
}
```

but I found that if I change the `!set.contains(i - 1)` to `set.contains(i-1)` it's still correct(leetcode accepted), but it should be `!set.contains(i - 1)`.

Anyone know the reasons?

```
class Solution {
/**
 * @param nums: A list of integers.
 * @return: A list of unique permutations.
 */
public List<List<Integer>> permuteUnique(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    if (nums == null) {
        return list;
    }

    if (nums.length == 0) {
        list.add( new ArrayList<Integer>() );
        return list;
    }

    Arrays.sort(nums);

    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    helper(nums, list, current, set);

    return list;
} 

public void helper(int [] nums, 
                   List<List<Integer>> list,
                   ArrayList<Integer> current,
                   HashSet<Integer> set){

    if(current.size() == nums.length) {
        list.add( new ArrayList<Integer>(current) );
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if ( set.contains(i) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if (i != 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1] && !set.contains(i-1) ) {
            continue;
        }

        current.add( nums[i] );
        set.add(i);
        helper(nums, list, current, set);
        set.remove(i);
        current.remove(current.size() - 1);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have the same confusion. Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Wiki page describes [permutation algorithm to get the next lexicographic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order), that works well with repeated elements. Pseudocode:

```
Initialisation: 
     Start with sorted combination - here [1,2,2]

Next permutation step:

   Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, 
   the permutation is the last permutation.

   Find the largest index l greater than k such that a[k] < a[l].

   Swap the value of a[k] with that of a[l].

   Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].
```